# Problemas de Carregando de Slider - Height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou usando um plugin para fazer um slider, chamado **Slick**.
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Estou deixando a imagem do slider com `width: 100%` para que a imagem fique boa a partir da resolução *1280px*.

Mas quando deixo assim o `height` do elemento pai que recebe os itens do slider fica com valor `auto`. E dessa forma no carregamento da página dá um BUG violento. Ele pega as imagens do slider e coloca uma em baixo da outra, depois de 1 segundo ou menos, que o `height` se adapta ao tamanho da imagem. Mesmo que eu coloque `overflow: hidden` no elemento pai acontece isso.

Agora se eu tiro o `width: 100%` da imagem e deixo ela ficar grande não acontece esse BUG, porquê a imagem vai ter uma altura fixa, então eu delimito isso no CSS e o BUG não acontece.

### CSS

```
div#slider-main-full {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    div.item{
        @include transition(0.5s, 0s);
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1920px;
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;

        img{
            width: 100%;            
        }
    }
}
```

### JS

```
var slick_carousel = $('#slider-main-full');

slick_carousel.slick({
    infinite: true,
    arrows: false,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    autoplay: true,
    speed: 3000,
    lazyLoad: 'progressive',
    cssEase: 'linear',
    fade: true,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    pauseOnFocus: false
});
```

Como eu faço para deixar que o HEIGHT seja automático e não aconteça esse BUG ?

:'(

Comment: Da-te jeito pôr o codigo no jsfiddle? era mais facil para te ajudar

Comment: Não dá para simular o BUG no JSFiddle.

Comment: Porque não tentas contornar isso com jquery?